# I want to change the color of card on click through Javascript have many cards and change single card color

Tags: javascript

> Blockquote I want to change the color of my card when i press the mark as important button but when i add two or three cards and click on a mark as important of a single card it will change the color of all cards
> Blockquote
> i want that if i click on mark as important button then a single card color will changed it will not change the color of all cards

```js
console.log("welcome to our website");
shownNotes();
impNotes();
let addbtn = document.getElementById("addbtn");
addbtn.addEventListener("click", handler)
function handler() {
    let txtarea = document.getElementById("txtarea");
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else {
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }
    notesObj.push(txtarea.value);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    txtarea.value = "";
    console.log(notesObj);
    shownNotes();
}

function shownNotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    let html = "";
    notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
        html +=
            `<div class="card mx-2 my-2 funny" style="width: 18rem;" >
           <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">${index}</h5>
         <p class="card-text">${element}</p>
         <button  id="${index} "onclick="delNotes(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
         <button  id="impbtn" onclick="impNotes(this.id)" class=" my-2 btn btn-primary">Mark Important</button>
           </div>
        </div>`
    });
    let notesElm = document.getElementById("notes");
    if (notesObj.length != 0) {
        notesElm.innerHTML = html;
    }
    else {
        notesElm.innerHTML = "<b>Nothing to show</b>"
    }
}
//function to delete notes 

function delNotes(index) {
    console.log("i m deleting", index)
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);

    notesObj.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    shownNotes();
}

// function to imp notes
function impNotes() {
    console.log("important function is firing ");
    let impbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("funny");
    Array.from(impbtn).forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Magic Notes</title>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>

<body>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Magic Notes</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container my-4 text-center">
        <h1>WELCOME TO MAGIC NOTES </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-sm card text-center ">

        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Add a Note </h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="txtarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn">Click me to add Note </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <Hr>
    <H1 class="text-center">Your Notes </H1>

    <div class="row justify-content-center" id="notes"></div>
    <!-- <hr> -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `impNotes()` function should take in a parameter that will help you identify which note color to change so impNote should be

```
function impNotes(id) {
    console.log("important function is firing ");
    let impbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("funny");
    Array.from(impbtn).forEach(function (element, index) {
    if(index === id) 
        element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    })
}
```

For you to pass argument to impNote you should change the code in showNotes()

```
function shownNotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    let html = "";
    notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
        html +=
            `<div class="card mx-2 my-2 funny" style="width: 18rem;" >
           <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">${index}</h5>
         <p class="card-text">${element}</p>
         <button  id="${index} "onclick="delNotes(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
         <button  id="impbtn" onclick="impNotes(${index})" class=" my-2 btn btn-primary">Mark Important</button>
           </div>
        </div>`
    });
    let notesElm = document.getElementById("notes");
    if (notesObj.length != 0) {
        notesElm.innerHTML = html;
    }
    else {
        notesElm.innerHTML = "<b>Nothing to show</b>"
    }
}
```

You pass `index` to impNote

Answer (score 0):

```
function shownNotes() {
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (notes == null) {
        notesObj = [];
    }
    else
        notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    let html = "";
    notesObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
        html +=
            `<div class="card mx-2 my-2 funny" id="card-${index}" style="width: 18rem;" >
           <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">${index}</h5>
         <p class="card-text">${element}</p>
         <button  id="${index} "onclick="delNotes(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
         <button  id="impbtn" onclick="impNotes('card-${index}')" class=" my-2 btn btn-primary">Mark Important</button>
           </div>
        </div>`
    });
    let notesElm = document.getElementById("notes");
    if (notesObj.length != 0) {
        notesElm.innerHTML = html;
    }
    else {
        notesElm.innerHTML = "<b>Nothing to show</b>"
    }
}
```

pass the id for each card based on index as shown and pass the id to impNotes method

```
function impNotes(id) {
        
    if(id) {
    let impbtn = document.getElementById(id);
   impbtn.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
    }
    
}
```